# Almost sure convergence, proof verification

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I have the sample space $\Omega = [0,1]$ and the random variable on that space $X_{n}(\omega)=n^{2}1_{[0,1/n]}(\omega).$ My goal is to prove that this random variable converges almost surely at 0.

My attempt:

From definition I have to prove that $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}\rightarrow 0)=1$

$\mathbb{P}(\left \{ \omega \in \Omega:\left | n^{2}1_{[0,1/n]}(\omega)\right |<\epsilon, \ \ \forall \ n\geq n_{0}  \right \}),$ where $\mathbb{P}$ the Lebesgue measure.

Inside the probability, we have that the inequality must hold for all $n\geq n_{0}$.

$\cap_{n\geq n_{0}}\left \{ \omega \in [0,1/n] \right \}=\cup_{n\geq n_{0}}\left \{ \omega\in [1/n,1] \right \}$

Because we work  with Lebesgue measure we have that

$\lambda(\cup_{n\geq n_{0}}\left \{ \omega\in [1/n,1]\right \})$ and $\left \{ \omega\in [1/n,1]\right \}$ are increasing events as $n$ increases.

Hence, from monotonicity

$\lambda(\cup_{n\geq n_{0}}\left \{ \omega\in [1/n,1]\right \})=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that $\mathbb P$ il the Lebesgue measure (otherwise, it's not true in general). Let $\omega \in(0,1]$. Let $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n}<\omega $ for all $n\geq N$. Then $$X_n(\omega )=0,$$
for all $n\geq N$. Therefore $X_n(\omega )\to 0$ for all $\omega \in (0,1]$, i.e. $X_n\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: Yes, as $\mathbb{P}$  I refer to Lebesgue measure